# Remove Item from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to make an `removeItem` method to remove items of String from `ArrayList`. The item gets removed, but I still get a `NullPointerException`, not really sure why.

```
/**
 * remove item
 */
public void removeItem(String description)
{
   Iterator<Item> i = items.iterator();      
   Item items = i.next();
   if items.getDescription().equals(description) {
    i.remove();
   }
   else {
       System.out.println("Invalid item description");
    }
   System.out.println("Item removed!");
}
```

Comment: There are several problems with this code. Note that it will always print `"Item removed"` even if it didn't removed anything.

Comment: Why not just use items.remove (description)?

Comment: And you could get a `NullPointerException` because probably `items` field is `null`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

You should use `.equals` to check if two strings are equals.

And, when you are using an iterator you should check if any item is avaitable using [`hasNext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext%28%29) method of the iterator.

There are anyway other methods like [`remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29) anyway!

Your code will be something like:

```
public void removeItem(String description)
{
    Iterator<Item> i = items.iterator();

    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        Item items = i.next();

        if (items.getDescription().equals(description))
        {
            i.remove();
            System.out.print("Item removed!");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

`return` because you should stop the `while` and exit the method if the item has been removed.

You should check if `items` and `getDescription` are not `null`!

With your code you will get a

> "Invalid item description"

everytime anyway.

Comment: Oh you are right, i just readed "Item not removed" not "Item removed"!

Comment: You are re-declaring `items` every iteration...
Using `return` as a break can cause undefined/difficult to define behavior- in this case, it means you stop as soon as you find the first match, and there might be other.
What if the the item description is null? What if items are null?
The return is void- if you truly want to remove a single item, standard practice is to return it...

Comment: @MirroredFate What? Item is a class, items takes the current iterator value and check if it's equal. `items` is inside the `while` to limitate his scope, and i'm not re-declaring anything.. it just takes the reference from `i.next()`

Comment: sorry, I capitalized the `i` and that was a typo.

Comment: @MirroredFate His code is supposed to print a message and return nothing.. if he need this kind of method he can change it..

Answer (score 0):

Try this - Using `hasNext()` method of Iterator & using null check

```
Iterator<Item> i = items.iterator();

while (i.hasNext()) {
    Item items = i.next();

    if (items.getDescription() != null && items.getDescription().equals(description)) {
        i.remove();
        System.out.print("Item removed!");
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has a number of problems. See the comments I added to your code.

```
/**
 * remove item
 */
public void removeItem(String description)
{
   Iterator<Item> i = items.iterator();  //ok, so the variable items is probably a class field
   Item items = i.next(); //...we just overwrote our class field items with the first item from iter...
   if items.getDescription().equals(description) { //we don't have parenthesis around our if statement...?
    i.remove(); //ok, we removed the item because it was equal
   }
   else {
       System.out.println("Invalid item description"); //it wasn't equal, so we say we got an invalid description
    }
    //aaaand apparently we are done. We only checked the first item in "items"
   System.out.println("Item removed!"); //this is outside of the if statement, so we will print this every time
}
```

So, let's clean up these problems. It seems like there could be multiple items with the same description, so let's change the method to reflect that as well.

```
/**
 * removes all the items with a matching description
 * returns the number of items removed
 */
public int removeItemsByDescription(String description) //make the method name reflect what it does
{
    //do we want to be able to check against a null description? because this changes if that is the case
    if(description == null)
         throw new NullPointerException("description was null");
    if(items == null) //make sure items is not null
         throw new NullPointerException("Items was null");
    Iterator<Item> itemsIter = items.iterator(); //more descriptive iterator name
    Item item; //ok, we name our single item "item" - and we just declare it here, we'll assign it later
    int removedItemNum = 0; //keep track of the total number of items we are removing
    while(itemsIter.hasNext()){//let's go through all the items
        item =  = itemsIter.next(); //get the next item
        if(description.equals(item.getDescription())){ //in order to avoid getting a null pointer exception when the description is null (which is probably perfectly valid), we will use description's .equals method
            itemsIter.remove(); //remove the item
            removedItemNum++; //increment the counter
        }
        //we don't need an else; if it didn't match, we just go on to the next one
    }
    System.out.println("Removed "+removedItemNum+" items");//print out how many we removed
}
```

And there we go! You should probably move that final print statement out of it when you are done testing.

Like I mentioned in the comments, this method changes if you want to be able to remove items with null descriptions (i.e., you want to pass in `null` as a valid parameter).